# Hollow Square Inside Hollow Square C#

Tags: c#

Hello is it possible to create this kind of patter using console c#?

Input 1: 5

Input 2 :3

Expected Output:

```
*****
* * *
*** *
*   *
*****
```

Here the top-left of the 5x5 box overlaps with the top-left of the 3x3 box.

I already tried to recreate this patter but i ended up with just whole square with cross inside

Example of my code below:

```
int num1,num2, i, j;

Console.WriteLine("Input 1");
num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Input 2");
num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

for(i = 0;i < num1;i++)
{
    for(j = 0;j < num1;j++)
    {
        if(i == 0 || i == num1 - 1)
        {
            Console.Write(" * ");
        }
        else if(j == 0 || j == num1 - 1)
        {
            Console.Write(" * ");
        }else if (j == num2 -1 || i == num2 -1){
            Console.Write(" * ");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write("   "); // space is printed ..
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("");
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Input 1: 5

Input 2: 3

Output:

```
*****
* * *
*****
* * *
*****
```

Comment: _"Hello is it possible to create this kind of patter using c#?"_ - Why wouldn't it be? - _"I already tried to recreate this patter but i ended up with just whole square"_ - if you want hlep with code, please show the code you want help with. Also, what does 3,5 signify?

Comment: "*is it possible to create this kind of patter using console c#*" - You will be happy to know the answer is a resounding yes

Comment: seems like a typical [homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) to me. can you please share what you've tried and researched so far? we'll gladly help if you're stuck somewhere, but you should first attempt to solve the task on your own - and be able to describe your efforts. i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: hello i accidentally submit it. i already edit my question

Comment: I have voted to reopen the question, since you have added the source code

Comment: @TheGeneral I don't know about you, but the goal doesn't seem entirely clear to me.

Comment: @Llama, yeah its not the most explanatory, however, the code does make it more than just a gimme ccodez question, and its relatively answerable all things considered.

Comment: OP: please edit your question to explain what inputs 1 and 2 are _supposed_ to do. For example: how does 3,5 lead to the output you've shown, but 5,3 leads to the second output shown? P.S. I understand it's the bounds for the two loops, but why is the printed output as it is in the question?

Comment: I already edit my question. i hope it is clear now.

Comment: Now you have two different examples for the input 5,3 with completely different outputs.

Comment: 1st example is what output i really need. while the 2nd example is my own code that i tried. but ended up with wrong pattern

Comment: Trying to not sound like a broken record here, but how do you get from 5,3 to the output you have displayed? What are the _rules_? It's completely unclear to me why the second line is `* * *` and the third line is `*** *`

Comment: users is the one who will input the 2 numbers. input 1 must be higher than input 2. as you can see i input number 5 that generate hollow box with 5 star each side. and input number 3 that generate hollow box inside of 1st hollow box with 3 star each side.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239264/discussion-between-rayner-pangan-and-llama).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're seeing the output you are is that you are also considering values beyond the edges of box 2 as being within the box (along edge lines).

[image]

That is to say that your intention is to draw the black lines and the blue lines, but you're continuing the vertical line down (red) and the horizontal line across (red). In these situations, you need to restrict the line vertically or horizontally to ensure you don't extend it too far.

I would create two flags for each of the boxes:

```cs
bool borderOfOuterBox = 
            i == 0 // top
            || j == 0 // left side
            || i == (num1 - 1) // bottom
            || j == (num1 - 1); // right side

bool borderOfInnerBox = 
            i == 0 // top
            || j == 0 // left side
            || (i == (num2 - 1) && j < num2) // bottom (note j is within the bounds of num2)
            || (j == (num2 - 1) && i < num2); // right side (not i is within the bounds of num2)
```

Then the whole check for writing becomes this:

```cs
bool borderOfOuterBox = i == 0 || j == 0 || i == (num1 - 1) || j == (num1 - 1);
bool borderOfInnerBox = i == 0 || j == 0 || (i == (num2 - 1) && j < num2) || (j == (num2 - 1) && i < num2);
if (borderOfOuterBox || borderOfInnerBox)
{
    Console.Write(" * ");
}
else
{
    Console.Write("   "); // space is printed ..
}
```

Comment: I already used it in my code and it worked.